# regex doubt in gawk

Tags: regex, gawk

my csv data file is like this

```
title,name,gender
MRS.,MADHU,Female
MRS.,RAJ KUMAR,male
MR.,N,Male
MRS.,SHASHI,Female
MRS.,ALKA,Female
```

now as you can see i wanna avoid all data like line 2 and 3 (i.e no white space or data length >= 3 )

```
MRS.,RAJ KUMAR,male
MR.,N,Male
```

and place it in a file called rejected_list.csv, rest all go in a file called clean_list.csv

hence here is my gawk script for it

```
gawk -F ',' '{ 
  if( $2 ~ /\S/  && 
      $1 ~ /MRS.|MR.|MS.|MISS.|MASTER.|SMT.|DR.|BABY.|PROF./ && 
      $3 ~ /M|F|Male|Female/) 
    print $1","$2","$3 > "clean_list.csv"; 
  else 
    print $1","$2","$3 > "rejected_list.csv" } ' \
< DATA_file.csv
```

My problem is this script is not recognising '\S' character set( all alphabets except space).. it is selecting all words starting with S or has a S and rejecting the rest

a simple regex like /([A-Z])/ in place of /s works perfectly but as i place a limit of {3,} the script fails..

```
gawk -F ',' '{ 
      if( $2 ~ /([A-Z]){3,}/ &&
          $1 ~ /MRS.|MR.|MS.|MISS.|MASTER.|SMT.|DR.|BABY.|PROF./ && 
          $3 ~ /M|F|Male|Female/) 
        print $1","$2","$3 > "clean_list.csv"; 
      else 
        print $1","$2","$3 > "rejected_list.csv" } ' \
 < DATA_file.csv
```

i have tried all sorts of combination of the regex with '*','+' etc but i cant get what i want...

can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: I have had some luck with escaping the `{}` characters - so `$2 ~ /([A-Z])\{3,\}/ && etc.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a rejection condition: not exactly 3 fields

```
gawk -F, '
  BEGIN { 
    titles = "MRS.|MR.|MS.|MISS.|MASTER.|SMT.|DR.|BABY.|PROF."
    genders = "M|F|Male|Female"
  }
  $1 !~ titles || $2 ~ /[[:space:]]/ || length($2) < 3 || $3 !~ genders || NF != 3 {
    print > "rejected_list.csv"
    next
  }
  { print > "clean_list.csv" }
' < DATA_file.csv
```

Comment: Glenn's use of `[[:space:]]` and declaring vars for `titles` and `genders` are a better solution to your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Use [:graph:] instead of \S for all printable and visible characters. GAWK does not recognize \S as [:graph:] so it will not work.

Additionally, the {3,} interval expression only works in posix or re-interval modes.

Comment: is there a way for Gawk understand posix mode. by setting some standard variable... something like IGNORECASE = 1 if u want to ignore case

Comment: They are gawk [command line options](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Options): `gawk --re-interval ...`